# CSS hide dd based on containing ID input

Tags: css

is it possible to hide a DD based on the containing input? The only selector i can use is the ID of the input...

Please no Javascript, i need CSS

```
<dd class="item-options">
 <input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_tablerate_evening_signature" name="ko_unique_27"> 
 <label class="label" for="s_method_tablerate_evening_signature">
</dd>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no parent selector in css

Comment: What is DD in your question?

Comment: @AkshayM - it would be <dd class="item-options">

Comment: Yep, thats the dd

Comment: You cannot target the parent - but you can hide the input and associated label in that dd and threfore collapse the dd down to have no height - i did an answer - but the question was closed before I could post -     #s_method_tablerate_evening_signature,
    #s_method_tablerate_evening_signature + label { 
      display: none;
    }